# DIfference between Select all href attributes and Select all anchor elements with href attributes using xpath with php

Tags: php, xpath, href

Given that in a html document all anchor elements have a href attribute that is set:

What is the difference between the following xpath queries

Case 1:

```
//@href
```

Case 2:

```
//a/@href
```

Case 3:

```
*/a/@href
```

In my situation:

`//@href` returns all the data contained in the href attribute.

`//a/@href` returns nothing but I expect it to return the same as `//@href`

`*/a/@href` returns nothing but I expect it to return the same as `//@href` and `//a/@href`

I fear that I am grossly misunderstanding how these queries work.  Is there anybody that can set me straight.  Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: you have accepted a very wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between the
>   following xpath queries
>
> Case 1:
>
> ```
> //@href
> ```

This selects all `href` attribute nodes in the XML document.

> Case 2:
>
> ```
> //a/@href
> ```

This selects all `href` attributes belonging to any element named `a` that is in no namespace.

> Case 3:
>
> ```
> */a/@href
> ```

This selects all `href` attributes belonging any element named `a` that is in no namespace and that is a grandchild of the current (context) node.

**Most probably you wanted to write**:

```
//*/a/@href
```

This selects all `href` attributes belonging any element named `a` that is in no namespace and whose parent is an element.

> In my situation:
>
> `//@href` returns all the data
>   contained in the `href` attribute.
>
> `//a/@href` returns nothing but I
>   expect it to return the same as
>   `//@href`
>
> `*/a/@href` returns nothing but I
>   expect it to return the same as
>   `//@href` and `//a/@href`
>
> I fear that I am grossly
>   misunderstanding how these queries
>   work. Is there anybody that can set me
>   straight. Thank you in advance for
>   your assistance.

**A very frequent situation is that the XML document has a default namespace. This is most probably the cause of your problem**. In this case no `a` element that is in "no namespace" exists in the document and any XPath expression having `a` as a location step selects nothing.

**Apart from this, the three expressions are not equivalent**.

`//@href` and `//a/@href`

could select different sets of nodes if in the document there are other elements except `a` that have an `href` attribute, or if the document is in a default namespace. In the last case the second expression selects nothing.

`//a/@href` and `//*/a/@href`

could select different sets of nodes if the top element of the document is an `a` that has an `href` attribute. The `href` attribute of this top element is selected by the first XPath expression but is not selected by the second, because the parent of the top element is not an element (it is the root node `/`).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown the source document. But I'm prepared to bet you've made the #1 XSLT mistake, which is to forget or fail to notice that it declares a default namespace, which means an unprefixed name like //a will not select any elements.

Comment: Here is a link to an example of one of the pages that I will be performing such searches on [http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/black-dragonflight/rustrazor/achievement#96]

Comment: under normal circumstances //a/@href and //@href should return the same result set.  So what is different about the document that I am working on that makes //a/@href return an empty set?

Comment: @Wes: See my answer for explanation.

Comment: @Wes: Google for "XPath default namespace". You need to use `//h:a` instead of `//a`, having first ensured (not sure how this is done in PHP) that the prefix h is bound to the namespace "w3.org/1999/xhtml" (or whatever the namespace actually is: the one you gave is a corruption of the XHTML namespace URI).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a node that has an attribute, use this syntax: `//a[@href]`.  I'm not entirely sure why the other method doesn't work, as it makes sense in principle.  Just how XPath is I guess.

Comment: When using this method I receive an empty set when i should essentially receive the same as //@href if what you are saying is rite and all anchors have a href value set (which they do)